# Declare classes using 'class' or 'function'

Tags: javascript

Right now, I know 2 different ways to declare a class.

Using `function`:

```
function test (constructor) {
  this.value = value;
}
test.prototype.method () {  
}
```

Using `class`:

```
class test {
  constructor(parameters) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  method () { 
  }
}
```

What is the difference (if any) between the two, and which should I use when?

Comment: New structure `class` does not exists in old JS implementations. `class` is just a *nice way to define function as class*, there is no OO in here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second *syntax* is the one you should use. It was introduced in ES6 standard and makes OOP in JS much easier. BTW, by convention class name is written in capital case.